# Closed and then reopened question samples

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Many new users are quite unaware of the required format of asking questions. A sample of closed questions that were edited and then reopened could be assistive for most of new users.

Also so far I have noticed a few new users use this site for homework questions. They should be warned right there that this site is not intended for homework solutions and could be referred to such a list, analyzing closed questions.

Comment: New members should spend some time looking at the site before they post. There are plenty of examples of good & bad questions (and answers) on the site.

Comment: i am saying show them how a closed question could be reopened with sample having "before and after" like things.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn’t understand your proposal from your question (v1), but I think I understand from your clarifying comment. Someone with skill at the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) might be able to produce a collection of recent “rescued” questions to serve as templates.

Comment: It seems like you have two ideas in one post here